conditions inside web component not working
I have an attribute within a grid in a Web Component in the pattern with work with plus, I put visibility conditions on it and it does not respect them, does anyone know what it could be? I am not using the data selector, if you know it can make it not respect the conditions
I couldn't do anything else, I can't find anything on the forums related to this topic.

Can yous hare the code you've tried so far, and what behavior you're seeing vs what you'd like to see? Also, specific versions of the tools in question?
